# Nodejs ssh2, how to connect when I don't have the keys

Tags: node.js, ssh

Ok, first off I have no real insight in how SSH works... I am using https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/ to try and do a "lookup" of an ip in a SSH server.

In Putty I can connect to the SSH server without user or password only by accepting the servers key (fingerprint).

When trying the same in ssh2 I only get "Error: Timed out while waiting for handshake".

Can anyone help in letting me know (and understand) if and how I can get this working?

Thanks!

Comment: Without a user? Do you have a default user set in your PuTTY configuration (Connection->Data)? Are you using ssh-agent or Pageant for authentication or do you have a private key set in your PuTTY configuration (Connection->SSH->Auth)?

Comment: I have the same setup and the same problem. There is NO username required and no private key required to login to the SSH server.
The only requirement is to accept the servers fingerprint in Putty and then I get the connection. User in Connection->Data is empty and there is no private key set in Putty.

I get the same error as TS in ssh2.

Comment: You must be using telnet or something else because ssh requires a username (from somewhere) and the ssh2 module wouldn't be giving you the handshake timeout error message if it was an actual ssh server (unless the connection is incredibly slow).

Comment: Nope, it is a SSH server... I have noticed that I can give any username, even a space and will get the connection. Added code as answer on how to connect through shell below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSH connection is done using public key only. The server then asks for a username and password.
After connection I immediately write the username to the stream followed by "Enter" and next the password. This gains me access to the server and I can trigger a SSH command (help) in the below case.

I hope this might help someone else struggling and since this is my first Node.js project please feel free to comment and help me with a better solution if you know of one!

```
var Connection = require('ssh2');

var c = new Connection();

c.host = '<ip/host>';
c.port = 22;
c.username = 'user';
c.password = 'password';

c.on('ready', function() {
console.log('Connection :: ready');
// If we got here we have a connection
// Start by creating a shell
c.shell(onShell);
});

var onShell = function(err, stream) { 
if (err != null) {
    console.log('error: ' + err);
}

var cmdcnt = 0;
stream.on('data', function(data, extended) {
    //console.log((extended === 'stderr' ? 'STDERR: ' : 'STDOUT: ') + data);
    console.log('[['+cmdcnt+'] '+data+']');

    var str_data = String(data);

    if (str_data.substr(data.length - 6) == 'xi52# ') {
        //We are logged in, start sending commands...
        if (cmdcnt == 2) stream.write('help\r');
    }

    // Set password after login, promtp #1
    if (cmdcnt == 1) stream.write(c.password+'\r');

    // command counter
    cmdcnt++;
});

stream.on('end', function() {
    console.log('Stream :: EOF');
});

stream.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Stream :: close');
});

stream.on('exit', function(code, signal) {
    console.log('Stream :: exit :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
    c.end();
});

// Send username at connect
stream.write(c.username+'\r');

//console.log('Shell');

} // End onShell function

c.on('error', function(err) {
console.log('Connection :: error :: ' + err);
});
c.on('end', function() {
console.log('Connection :: end');
});
c.on('close', function(had_error) {
console.log('Connection :: close');
});

c.connect({
host: c.host,
port: c.port,
username: c.username,
password: ''
});
```